# Why is this Custom Report not showing all records?

Tags: reporting, custom-field, custom-report-type

In order to build a mailing list our marketing team could use on a regular basis I have created two custom fields on our Account Object, that relate to two different contacts.

I then created a custom report type that looks at Contacts with Accounts.

This works for one of the fields but for some reason not the other.

Both fields have been included in the Custom Report Type, and there are no hierarchy settings saved for the report and I am an admin.

Comment: When you have two or more relationships to the same object, the report can only follow one relationship, it can't traverse the other relationships for data.

Have you considered using Account Contact Roles instead of these custom lookup fields?

Comment: @DavidCheng part of the issue is that I need to be able to run the report on the Account, Specific Contacts, and a custom object that stores product subscriptions related only to the account.

Comment: If you used contact roles, you might be able to build use the Accounts with Contact Roles report type and add a cross-filter on your custom object, but it's hard to say without knowing more details about what you are trying to do.